# Finding the actual Class of an object that was passed to a method using an ancestor class

Tags: java

If I pass an object like this:

```
class Car {}

Audi extends Car {}

do.something(Car car) { }

Audi audi = new Audi();
do.something(audi);
```

How can I find out that car is an `Audi`?

Assuming that also `Car` does not necessarily have any specific subclass that was passed and could actually be just a generic `Car`.

What if we had:

```
A4 extends Audi {}
```

then

```
A4 a4 = new a4();
do.something(a4);
```

`A4` will be a grandchild of the `Car` class... so how do we know the `car` is an `A4` in this case?

and so on...

Comment: That's a sign of bad design; you should not need to know that.

Comment: I only use it for my logging code... this way I can pass the log() method nothing at all describing what Class called it but then log() can still use that information when it writes the log. Keeps my code cleaner in the rest of the program.

Comment: ok I wasn't thinking... my log code uses getStackTrace().. not objects.. have to rethink my whole question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the class over reflections.

```
public void something(Car car){
    String carName = car.getClass.getSimpleName();
    System.out.println("CarName: " + carName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is necessity of it, then use [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator

```
if(car instanceof Audi)
```

Btw instanceof should be used as a last resort, read this for more info: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Comment: It shouldn't be `instanceOf` , it is `instanceof`. Hope you don't mind

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I edited before you could comment, anyways Thanks! ;-)

Comment: when I saw, it was capital O, well no problems :)

Comment: instanceof not an option, since it could be any subclass... that was just an example... but for instance... let's say there is a BMW or whatever too... and 50 other types of cars...

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `instanceof` operator to determine what is the actual class of the object that is passed into your method. But as pointed out in the comments it's a bad OO design to rely upon inheritance hierarchy to build too complex internal logic.

Answer (score 1):

you can have

```
if(car instanceof Audi)
```

or

```
if(car.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(Audi.class.getSimpleName())
```